# Raspberry Pi Camera capture circular buffer and following (x) amount of seconds

Tags: python, camera, raspberry-pi

I recently got the camera module for the Raspberry Pi. Working through their circular buffer example found [here (code shown below.)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/python-picamera-setup/worksheet.md)

My goal is to save the 20 second buffer built in "stream = picamera.PiCameraCircularIO(camera, seconds=20)" but also to continue to record for 30 seconds. Below the main thing I have added to their example is "time.sleep(30)" following the GPIO input on Pin 17. When I run this it sometimes produces a file but that file is never playable. I'd appreciate any advice or suggestions you have to offer.

Code:

```
import io
import time
import picamera
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_UP)

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    stream = picamera.PiCameraCircularIO(camera, seconds=20)
    camera.start_recording(stream, format='h264')
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(17, GPIO.FALLING)
    time.sleep(30)
    camera.stop_recording()
    for frame in stream.frames:
        if frame.header:
            stream.seek(frame.position)
            break
    with io.open('/home/pi/Desktop/video.h264', 'wb') as output:
        while True:
            data = stream.read1()
            if not data:
                break
            output.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that a better method is to replace:

```
time.sleep(30)
```

by

```
camera.wait_recording(30)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are starting a Circular buffer correctly which will hold 20 seconds of video.
The last 20 seconds of video. Waiting 30 seconds however is futile however as it will only ever hold 20 seconds of video.

If you read the picamera docs (picamera.readthedocs.org) in the advanced recipes they show you how to use split_recording to preserve the contents of the circular buffer which you can then write while a second IO (a file or stream) records what is currently happening.

NOW you camera.wait_recording(30) and then split_recording back to another IO (in the advanced recipe it is the original, truncated, CircularIO).

At the end of this you will have two files. One containing the buffer i.e. 20 seconds before and another containing the 30 seconds after. Then you concat these two together and voila, you now have a 50 second video. Mp4Box does this well enough.

Now I have been trying very hard to use io.open to concatenate these two streams on the fly but I suspect that there are some header details/info that get messed with when you io.open('blah.h264', 'ab') which mean that you only get the last appended video. I don't suppose anyone reading this is an h264 encoding boffin?